# Trigger action when file download actually completes

Tags: php

Nowdays there are a lot of websites for files hosting (`uploading websites`) and it count for example point per complete download of certain file.

**My question**
I want to understand what is the idea they are using !

***How*** does it only count on ***complete*** downloading of the file ?!
i mean if i ***canceled downloading*** of the file after it started , it won't count point!
how does it knew ! is there any php function that able to know if i canceled downloading certain exact file or not !

that question was all time in my mind and thinking about it but i can't understand how does it works or what is the idea behind it. ~ thanks

Comment: @JackSpairow i think downvote is the answer :) maybe stupid question but i really interested about how such websites doing this or what is the idea behind it !

Comment: You can do it using the web server log. For apache check mod_logio, it can be set to log the bytes sent and bytes received. So if bytes sent = bytes received, the file download was successful. I don't think that you can do it with PHP only.

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using my other answer as base [How can I give download access to files outside public_html directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10273048/1338846) and replacing `readfile( $filename )`
with `readfileWhileConnected( $filename )`:

### Read file until EOF or disconnect:

```php
/** Read $filename until EOF or disconnect, 
 * if disconnect then error_log() count of bytes read already 
 */
function readfileWhileConnected( $filename ) {
    // Save and set ini values:
    $user_abort = ignore_user_abort();
    ignore_user_abort(false);
    // Get file size and set bytes_sent to zero:
    $fsize = filesize($filename);
    $bytes_sent = 0;
    // Open file:
    $f = fopen($filename, 'r');
    // Read file:
    while($chunk = fread($f, 1024)) {
        // Check if connection is still open:
        if(!connection_aborted()) {
            // Send $chunk to buffer (if any), then flush() buffers:
            echo $chunk;
            flush();
            // Add $chunk length to $bytes_sent
            $bytes_sent += strlen($chunk);
        } else {
            // Close file:
            fclose($f);
            error_log("Connection closed at $bytes_sent/$fsize");
            exit();
        }
    // Close file:
    fclose($f);
    // Reset ini values:
    ignore_user_abort($user_abort);
    return $bytes_sent;
    }
}
```

After you have your new shiny `class myNewSuperDownloadHandlerClass { ... }` ready, then make sure you only serve downloads through `filedownload.php` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10273048/1338846) or if have done good `myNewSuperDownloadHandlerClass()`, then use that, just make sure that `readfileWhileConnected()` is used for every download requiring connection status polling.

You can easily add callback to be triggered if user closes connection, only 2 exit points here. *(seen many functions that have every often `return false; return true; return null; return false; return true;` and so on..)*